# Javascript Dom table Pagination

Tags: javascript, dom, pagination

I am new to JavaScript. I tried adding pagination to JavaScript table, but the table is not formed and search/sort also don't work. Below is the code I tried for pagination. I think problem is in integration of pagination with my main code.

fiddle of my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/ujv1cxna/2/
file: https://files.fm/f/yf5hbk7e

output:

[image]

```
var list =tableObj.rows;
  var pages = paginate(10, list);
        function paginate(n, list) {
            return divide(n, list).map(function (items, index) {
                var number = n * index;

                return {
                    start: number + 1,
                    end: number + items.length,
                    items: items
                };
            });
        }

        var header = document.getElementById("pageHeader");
        var items = document.getElementById("pageItems");
        var buttons = document.getElementById("pageButtons");

        appendChildren(buttons, pages.map(function (page, index) {
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.addEventListener("click", display);
            button.innerHTML = index + 1;
            return button;

            function display() {
                displayPage(page);
            }
        }));

        displayPage(pages[0]);

        function displayPage(page) {
            header.innerHTML = "Items " + page.start + " to " + page.end + ":";

            items.start = page.start;

            items.innerHTML = "";

            appendChildren(items, page.items.map(function (item) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerHTML = item;
                return li;
            }));
        }

        function appendChildren(element, children) {
            children.forEach(function (child) {
                element.appendChild(child);
            });
        }

        function take(n, list) {
            return list.slice(0, n);
        }

        function drop(n, list) {
            return list.slice(n);
        }

        function concat(lists) {
            return Array.prototype.concat.apply(this, lists);
        }

        function divide(n, list) {
            if (list.length) {
                var head = take(n, list);
                var tail = drop(n, list);
                return concat.call([head], [divide(n, tail)]);
            } else return [];
        }
    buildTable(tableObj.headers, list);
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve your problem,

Here is my updated [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/manishkrsingh/4smj9g8e/)

I made the following changes.

1. Created Next, Prev and a place to show current page.
2. Created one Object called pagination, This is responsible for doing prev, next or reset pagination.

**After loading the data to table from file, you need to call pagination.init()**, so that it will set pagination to initial stage.

In init function only I am setting events for next and prev buttons.

```
var pagination = {
                currentPage: 0,
                itemPerPage: 2,
                currentPageItems: [],
                next: function () {
                    if(!!tableObj.rows && (tableObj.rows.length >= (this.itemPerPage*(this.currentPage+1)))) {
                        var startIndex = this.itemPerPage*this.currentPage;
                        ++this.currentPage;
                        var endIndex = (this.itemPerPage*this.currentPage);
                        pagination.currentPageItems = tableObj.rows.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

                        buildTable(tableObj.headers, pagination.currentPageItems);
                        document.getElementById("current-page-number").textContent = "Page Number: "+this.currentPage;
                    } else {
                        alert("No Items to go next")
                    }
                },
                prev: function () {
                    --this.currentPage;
                    if ((this.currentPage - 1) >= 0) {
                        var endIndex = this.itemPerPage*this.currentPage;
                        --this.currentPage;
                        var startIndex = (this.itemPerPage*this.currentPage);
                        pagination.currentPageItems = tableObj.rows.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
                        buildTable(tableObj.headers, pagination.currentPageItems);
                        document.getElementById("current-page-number").textContent = "Page Number: "+this.currentPage;
                    } else {
                        alert("Not allowed");
                        this.currentPage = 0;
                    }
                },
                reset: function () {
                    this.currentPage = 0;
                    this.currentPageItems = [];
                },
                init: function() {
                    this.reset();
                    this.next();
                    document.getElementById("gotonext").onclick = function() {
                        pagination.next()
                    };
                    document.getElementById("gotoprev").onclick = function() {
                        pagination.prev();
                    };
                }
            };
```

**pagination.currentPageItems** is holding the data for current view(page), so you need to do filter or sorting operation on pagination.currentPageItems only. This will filter/Sort data of current page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving it.